# generate documentation file for laravel routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, documentation

I know it's possible to print all routes with `php artisan route:list`

But is there a way to generate some kind of documentation for it?

For example I am developing an api with well documented code. When another person wants to use this api he can look up in this file where are all routes with the required parameters, the output an some description are described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible with [phpDocumentor](https://www.phpdoc.org/). Sample command from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37046776/how-to-generate-documentation-of-my-laravel-project):

```
phpdoc -d path/to/my/project -f path/to/an/additional/file -t path/to/my/output/folder
```

You can also try [ApiGen](http://www.apigen.org/)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response :) I found `laravel-apidoc-generator` that does exactly what I want